# ExtJS 3.2 Built In Icons?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Does ExtJS 3.2 have built in icons that you can use? I see that the latest version does but cannot find anything on 3.2

```js
  Ext.MessageBox.show({
     msg: 'Getting data, please wait...',
     progressText: 'Loading...',
     width:300,
     wait:true,
     waitConfig: {interval:200},
     icon:'browser', //This is one for version 6.
     animEl: 'mb7'
 });
```

Comment: Did Windows 3.1 have Aero? I see that the latest version does but I cannot find anything on 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have following icons in Ext Js 3.2 which is present in `Ext.MessageBox` object:

```
CANCEL
ERROR
INFO
QUESTION
WARNING
```

Usage example :

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({
   msg: 'Getting data, please wait...',
     progressText: 'Loading...',
     width:300,
     wait:true,
     waitConfig: {interval:200},
   icon: Ext.MessageBox.QUESTION,
animEl: 'mb7'
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I will make use of these as needed.